# Is there a way to put "X" amount of arguments in command, depending on how many items in a list?

Tags: python

(Question not related to pyqt)

Hello.

I am not sure how to ask this question correctly. Probably there is an easy way in front of my eyes or I am over complicating things, but for example let's say -

I have piece of script taken from PyQt and it will look something like this :

```
points = [[0.2, -4.0, 0.0]]
QtGui.QPolygonF([QtCore.QPointF(points[0][0], points[0][1])])
```

or if making it "for" loop:

```
for point in points:
    QtGui.QPolygonF([QtCore.QPointF(point[0], point[1])])
```

Question : how to make "for" loop if there is a case with multiple lists, how do you guys iterate thru list and put it in command?

For example something like this :

Usual :

```
points = [[0.2, -4.0, 0.0], [0.1, -3.0, 0.0], [0.5, -5.0, 0.0]]
QtGui.QPolygonF([QtCore.QPointF(points[0][0], points[0][1]),(points[1][0], points[1][1]), (points[2][0], points[2][1])])
```

"for" loop :

```
for point in points:
    ?????
```

Side note - we don't know how many lists are nested in list "points", it will change case by case.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list comprehension will work nicely in this case:

```
points = [[0.2, -4.0, 0.0], [0.1, -3.0, 0.0], [0.5, -5.0, 0.0]]
Qt.Gui.QPolygonF([QtCore.QPointF(v1, v2) for v1, v2, v3 in points])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It answers question I asked , I will mark it as correct :) but i did mistake in my question , so if you know , can you tell me what to do if code should look something like this : QtGui.QPolygonF([QtCore.QPointF(p[0][1], p[0][2]), QtCore.QPointF(p[1][1], p[1][1]), QtCore.QPointF(p[2][1], p[2][1]), QtCore.QPointF(p[3][1], p[3][1])]) . So problem is that I have to write "QtCore.QPointF" everytime there is new "points" and I don't know every time how many lists are nested. List comprehension helps if the problem is just putting all list under one command. Thank you

Comment: How is your list `points` actually structured? There's not much we can do if your data isn't structured in a predictable pattern. In the example in your comment above, the first `QPointF` uses the first and second elements of the first nested list, but then the remaining points use only the first element of your other nested lists. I'd recommend rearranging the data before calling `QPolygonF`. If that was just a typo on your end, I'm not sure what you're asking - my answer should work for any number of points inside the list `points`.